# How to set service manager globally from a controller in zf2?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

In normal way i can able to define an object through out the application  by defining a service factory in configuration file global.php

i can get the object in controller by just calling `$this->getServiceLocator()->get('mycollection')`

My code as follows:
In global.php

```
service_manager' => array(
        'factories' => array(  
                  'mycollection'=> function($sm){
                        $collectionAdapter = new Collection();
                        $collectionAdapter->addItem("testvalue",'test');
                        return $collectionAdapter;
                    }
```

By adding in global file i can able to retrieve

```
//`var_dump($this->getServiceLocator()->get('mycollection')->getItem("test"));// will return testvalue`
```

through out the application

But my issue is that  i dont know how to accomplish set values to the service from a controller

My requirement is that i need to set the service in one controller and retrieve in another module

i tried the following code in my IndexController album module

```
$this->getServiceLocator()->get('mycollection')->addItem('testvalue28','test8');
```

and in another  module student IndexController called

```
//var_dump($this->getServiceLocator()->get('mycollection')->getItem("test8"));//
```

How can i accomplish the same which i set in global.php in a controller . or more clearly i need to store the collection values to the entire application at one instance in all modules

**Edited**

1)The function addItem  will be set only based on controller action 
2)Is there any thing similar to ZEND_REGISTERY where i can set a value form a particular request and retrieve in another action

//An application controller is define where i need to set different key value pair

```
namespace Application\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;
class IndexController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function authenticateAction()
    {
    //----other code---------
    var_dump($this->getServiceLocator()->get('mycollection')->addItem('userauthenticationobj','userkey'));
    //$redirect=module=user  controller action =index
    return $this->redirect()->toRoute($redirect);
    }
}
```

In user module index action i need to get the key value pair  which is set inside application module in index action. i know this can be done using a session or db or cookies but i want to implement this using a singleton instance through out the application. i don't know to define the correct term in oops so defining the situation
//User controller

```
namespace User\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;
class IndexController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function authenticateAction()
    {
    //----other code---------
    var_dump($this->getServiceLocator()->get('mycollection')->addItem('userkey'));
    //$redirect=module=user  controller action =index
    return $this->redirect()->toRoute($redirect);
    }
}
```

//IN GLOBAL.PHP i defined

```
return array(
    'service_manager' => array(
        'factories' => array(
                    'mycollection'=> function($sm){
                    $collectionAdapter = new Collection();
                    $collectionAdapter->addItem("testvalue",'test');
                    return $collectionAdapter;
                }
         ),
    ),
);
```

//user defined collection reference: http://www.sitepoint.com/collection-classes-in-php/

```
namespace Application\Adapter;
    class Collection 
    {
        private $items = array();
        public function addItem($obj, $key = null)
        {
            if ($key == null)
            {
                $this->items[] = $obj;
            }
            else {
                if (isset($this->items[$key])) 
                {
                    throw new \Exception("Key $key already in use.");
                }
                else
                 {
                    $this->items[$key] = $obj;
                 }
            }
        }
        public function getItem($key)
        {
            if (isset($this->items[$key]))
            {
                return $this->items[$key];
            }
            else
            {
                throw new \Exception("Invalid key $key.");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you wanting to set a value in one controller and access from another module within the same request? If yes, can you provide a bit more info on your use case?

Comment: i elaborated the content , home this should make it more clear

Answer (score 0):

If you are in the same request (this is, the user is not following links, or the page is not being refreshed) the service manager will keep the Collection alive and what you are trying should work.

But if you are redirecting the user to another controller/action, or the user has followed a link, submited a form, or whatever that causes a new page to be loaded, all the values created in the previous page wont exists anymore. If you need to persist them, you should use sessions, cookies, database, etc.

If the values are not set during the action, i.e you dont need a controller to be loaded, but you need all the controllers to be able to add values to the collection on the application bootstrap, no matter what controller is actually loaded, you can add some code to every module, in Module.php onbootstrap function. for instance, in every module's Module.pho, you do:

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e) { 

    $sm = $e->getApplication ()->getServiceManager ();
    $collection = $sm->get('mycollection');
    $collection->addItem('testvalue_N','test_N');
}
```

and then, in every controller/action that is executed, you will have the collection with all the items added by all the modules

Comment: can you go through the edited portion of my question